# Angular ui.router default header footer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-include

When it comes to ui.router modules I can think of three different ways to set a default header and footer for every view:

```
DEFAULT HEADER
<CONTENT>
DEFAULT FOOTER
```

### 1. ng-include - attaching your header / footer into your initial .html file (index.html).

```
<html>
<div ng-include src="'header.html'"></div>
<div id="content" ui-view></div>
```

**1.1. Pasting code into index.html**

```
<html>
<div><!-- my header code here --></div>
<div id="content" ui-view></div>
```

### 2. Using directives to parse the header and footer.

home.html

```
<!-- content -->
<!-- /content -->
<footer></footer>
```

footerDirective.js

```
module.directive('footer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "footer.html",
        controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
        }]
    } 
});
```

http://gon.to/2013/03/23/the-right-way-of-coding-angularjs-how-to-organize-a-regular-webapp/

### 3. Creating an extra **state on ui.router** with no url.

State wrapper would then contain the header and footer and won't be callable.

```
$stateProvider
.state('wrapper', {
    templateUrl: 'wrapper.html', // contains html of header and footer
    controller: 'WrapperCtrl'
})
.state('wrapper.home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
});
```

Which one is preferred? Or, is there a more desirable way to do it with Angular 1.x?

Comment: Use the 2nd way. Create custom tag (wrap your own components) is a recommend approach of code reuse. You can add control logic, some time when you have the need, without changing any code where the tag is used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is also another way where you take advantage of the state's `views` property. It enables one to define multiple named views for a certain state. [UI docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Consider the below example where state myapp has three named views, where the content view will be the view with dynamic content.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myapp', {
        views: {
          'header': {
            template:'header <hr />',
            controller:'mainController as main'
          },
          'content': {
            template:'<div ui-view></div>'
          },
          'footer': {
            template:'<hr /> footer',
            controller:'mainController as main'
          }
       }
   })
  //States below will live in content view
  .state('myapp.one', {
    template:'View 1 <button ui-sref="myapp.two">next page</button>',
    controller:'firstController as first',
  })
  .state('myapp.two', {
    template:'Another page <button ui-sref="myapp.one"> Go back</button>',
    controller:'secondController as second',
  })
```

And the HTML will look like this:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"><!-- Where your content will live --></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

[Jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/xalakuqato/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: A bonus for doing it this way is that you can redefine the header or footer in a substate, like `.state('myapp.one.substate',  { views: "header@myapp": { template: "<h1>New header for myapp.one.substate.*" } })`